# MySql Server Problem

Tags: linux, mysql

I am trying to connect a remote mysql server but when I try to connect then I get following error:

**ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'My Server IP' (110)**

**Possibilities (Found over the web) :**
**1.** May be local computer's outgoing connection not allowed from where I am connecting.
    I have tried to connect another remote mysql remote server which is accessible. So its mean there is not any error related to outbound rule.
**2.** May be remote server's port is not public.
 - I have tried to connect same server which is not accessible from Computer A, with Computer B and its working fine with Computer B.

**Advice?**

Have u any idea what can be wrong except above possibilities?

thanks in advace

Comment: Double-check the IP of the server. Try ping to ensure it's available from your PC. Usually mysql runs on port 3306, try connecting to this port directly using 'telnet' or PuTTY in Windows. Check you have mysql running on server side (you should see it in process list), ensure firewall doesn't block port 3306.

Answer (score 1):

The [Error Code 2003](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-client.html#error_cr_conn_host_error) is a error that is returned by Mysql client. On your server do the following.

```
netstats -ntlp |grep 3306
```

You should get a result similar to

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q   Local Address         Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0   0.0.0.0:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

If the Local Address is 127.0.0.1 then your mysql is listening on loopback and you not be able to connect from any other host, modify the settings in my.cnf and restart mysql. If Local Address is 0.0.0.0 check your firewall settings.

Heads up. After solving the remote connectivity the next problem that you will run in to will be access denied error, because you wouldn't have the appropriate [grants.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)